# My boy just turned 4 and is about to start Pre-kindergarten. He won't poop in potty, only pull-ups

Tags: pre-schooler, potty-training, elimination

I don't know what to do. He won't do poop in potty. He is completely pee trained, no accidents. It even takes him forever to go poop in pull-ups because he is playing. He is an only child. He will just start [Pre-kindergarten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-kindergarten) this year. Need help fast! Tried so much for 6 months. About to start Pre-kindergarten where he has to be potty trained.

Comment: Have you spoken to the teacher/carer at Pre-Kindergarten? Because what we found is that they are fully prepared for the idea that some children won't have quite made it all the way, and can cope perfectly well. Obviously you'll want to get him to full potty training, but they will support you in that.

Answer (score 2):

Each child is different and different things work for different families. You may have tried these all but I hope something may help.

- Take it in stages. He could be uncomfortable or scared about the idea of doing poos in the toilet so it's about easing him into getting comfortable with this idea.

So you could try easing him into the process through first getting him to go in his pull up in a specific place in the house. Like a corner or somewhere he feels safe. Then once this is done and he is fine going in a specific place, and not just anywhere while he keeps on playing then change that place to become the bathroom. So he gets used to going poos in the bathroom in his pull up. Then instead of going anywhere in the bathroom get him to sit on the toilet in his pull up and go poos. Then once he is comfortable with this step then you could move on to him actually going in the toilet itself, with a pull up pulled down. Slowly working though the steps so he is comfortable with each one before moving to the next.

Other ideas:

- Incentives can work well for some children. A very special treat if he goes on the toilet. Like the best treat you can think of for him. The good old sticker or stamp chart is another option that has worked wonders for many children I've known.
- positive motivation to use the toilet through explaining that if you stop buying him pull ups the money could be put towards something more fun.
- what happens when you let him have an 'accident'? The mess is not ideal but sometimes the discomfort can motivate children to use the toilet.
- peer pressure. As an only child this may be a good motivator. Does he have many friends his age who are not having this problem? Hanging out or spending time with them may help him see that going on the toilet is not so scary. Perhaps when he starts pre-k and he sees lots of other children using the toilet he will start to do the same.

Good luck and he will get there with time if nothing else.